# Redirect "any page/page/number/" to "any page"

Tags: redirect, pagination, htaccess

I've read so many similar topics but none of them matches my own request.

I'd like to redirect in `ht.access` any page with pagination to the root-main-original page.

`example.com/garden/page/2`
redirected to `example.com/garden/`

`example.com/house/bedroom/page/14`
redirected to `example.com/house/bedroom/`

`example.com/cat/subcat1/subcat2/subcat3/subcat4/page/3/`
redirected to `example.com/cat/subcat1/subcat2/subcat3/subcat4/`

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to redirect in `ht.access`

To clarify, it's `.htaccess`, not `ht.access`.

<sup>(The filename "ht.access" is sometimes used for an *example* config, it's not processed by Apace and would need to be renamed if there is not already a `.htaccess` file - there should be.)</sup>

You can do something like the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing WordPress directives:

```
RewriteRule (.*/)page/\d+/?$ /$1 [R=302,L]
```

The above issues a 302 (temporary) redirect for any URL of the form `/<something>/page/<number>/` (trailing slash optional) to `/<something>/`.

The `$1` backreference contains the captured URL-path before the `page/<number>/` part at the end of the URL-path.

Always test with a 302, even if this should be a 301 (permanent) redirect later.

There is no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive, since that should already appear later in the file.

Comment: How can we redirect  permanent? Where should we using 301?

Comment: I have a url like this https://www.example.com/category/blog/page/5/ but it's not redirecting

Comment: @NarenVerma Change `R=302` to `R=301` to make it a _permanent_ redirect. This rule would redirect a URL of the form `https://www.example.com/category/blog/page/5/`, providing you've put the rule in the appropriate place at the _top_ of the _root_ `.htaccess` file.